# Prepared MySQL Statement fails insert with no error

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm  using MySQL to try and add a new user to my database. User got an Id, a First Name, a Last Name and a Date of Birth. But when I run the code below (And run `conn.close()` after I'm done) the database tells me (using HeidiSQL) that in the Table Overview there is now a new row in the table but when I open the Data Tab to look at the rows, there is nothing. It's empty. Running a `COUNT(*)` also returns 0.

```
using (MySqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USERS(NAME_FIRST,NAME_LAST,DATE_OF_BIRTH) VALUES(@nameFirst,@nameLast,@dateOfBirth)";
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameFirst", user.NameFirst);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameLast", user.NameLast);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", user.DateOfBirth);
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lastInsertId = (uint)cmd.LastInsertedId;
    }
}
```

I get no errors. Nothing shows up in any log and everyone sees the same as me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @john I used @ somewhere else without any issue

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken :-) It has been a while.

Comment: In the table overview in what sql client. If you run this multiple times does your table overview say 2, 3, 4, etc..?

Comment: Are you certain that the connection is working?  If you try to run a select in different method, can you get back data?  Your statement looks fine to me.

Comment: @JNevill Yes, the row count just keeps going up but no new data shows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I have successfully run SELECT in my code and gotten data back. I  can only insert data in HeidiSQL. I can't do it via my code.

Comment: Is the `user` object defined, and are its fields also defined?

Comment: Oh! Heidisql. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, the user object is fine.

Comment: Any chance `Autocommit` is turned off for the server? Have you experienced this issue with any other tables or is the first one run through C#?

Comment: @JNevill First attempt. It's part of a RESTful API I'm  making.

Comment: Try debugging the code and/or wrapping the database calls with a try catch block.

Comment: Are you using innodb or myisam?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have done that. No exceptions are ever caught.

Comment: @JNevill innodb

Comment: I think it's the use of `begintransaction` which starts a transaction which means `autocommit=false` for the entirety of the transaction. After `ExecuteNonQuery` Do a `transaction.Commit();` and see if they show up. [More Info Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx)

Comment: @JNevill I included `cmd.Transaction.Commit()` and now it works..it's a commit issue. Damn it  =_=

I'd like you to make an answer though, so you can have it :)

Comment: Added as an answer. Perhaps it will help someone else in the future. That is a tricky one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like it's the use of `begintransaction` which starts a transaction. This means `autocommit=false` for the entirety of the transaction.

After `ExecuteNonQuery` Do a `transaction.Commit();` and see if they show up.

[More Info Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx)

Comment: This was the issue, yes.

Comment: I'm glad that did the trick. I've never monkeyed with manual commits before, but this one felt like some of that wonkiness.